# Wrong count on inner join of the same table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

﻿﻿﻿﻿I have a big table with millions of records and new records are added everyday. My goal is to only update the min/max/total of the newly inserted rows. But I am not getting the correct `count()`.

```
sqlite> select rowid, * from t1;                                                   
1, james, 0                                                                        
2, james, 6                                                                        
3, peter, 8                                                                        
4, james, 4                                                                        
5, james, 0                                                                        
6, peter, 0                                                                        
7, james, 6                                                                        
8, james, 5                                                                        
9, peter, 0                                                                        
10, james, 7                                                                       
11, james, 7
```

The sql I am using:

```
sqlite> select t1.name, max(t1.score), min(t1.score), count(*) from 
t1 join t1 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name 
where t2.rowid > 9 group by t2.name;

james, 7, 0, 16
```

I am expecting `james, 7, 0, 8`

```
sqlite> select t1.name, max(t1.score), min(t1.score), count(t1.name) 
from t1 join t1 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name 
where t2.rowid > 5 group by t2.name;
                                                                                   
james, 7, 0, 32                                                                    
peter, 8, 0, 6
```

I am expecting

```
james, 7, 0, 8                                                                     
peter, 8, 0, 3
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Why are you joining the same table twice? I can't see a reason for that

Comment: This is a append only table. Lets say today it only adds records of james. then I want to only update james' min/max/total because updating all takes too long. I also keep track of the `max(id)` before updating hence the `rowid >` part.

Comment: oh, I found all the duplicated rows by removing the group by clause. Now I get the correct count by changing `count(t1.name)` to `count(distinct t1.name)`